# Does it make sense to assign a value to a variable declared with var statement only inside those blocks where it is used?

Tags: javascript

Let's consider that

- some variable is declared by var statement inside a javascript function;
- this variable will have its value unchanged throughout the function;
- this variable will be used only inside some of the blocks within that function, but it is not going to be used inside majority of the blocks.

**Question:** If all above mentioned is true, then is it better to assign a value (which is not going to be changed) to the variable only once, at the beginning of the function declaration outside the blocks, or assign same value repeatedly inside only those few blocks where variable is used?

In following examples there are 5 blocks inside the function declaration, but variable x is used only inside 2 of them. But let's suppose there are much more blocks and only few of them involve variable x;

**Example 1:** In this example variable x has its value assigned only once at the beginning of function declaration, outside all the blocks:

```
function foo() {
    var x;
    x = 'value';
    if (ConditionNotInvolvingX) {
        // do something without using x
    }
    else if (Condition2NotInvolvingX) {
        console.log(x);
    }
    else if (Condition3NotInvolvingX) {
        console.log('""' + x + '""');
    }
    else if (Condition4NotInvolvingX) {
        // do something without using x
    }
    else if (Condition5NotInvolvingX) {
        // do something without using x
    }
}
```

**Example 2:** In this example variable x has its value assigned repeatedly only inside those 2 blocks, where it is needed:

```
function foo() {
    var x;
    if (ConditionNotInvolvingX) {
        // do something without using x
    }
    else if (Condition2NotInvolvingX) {
        x = 'value';
        console.log(x);
    }
    else if (Condition3NotInvolvingX) {
        x = 'value';
        console.log('""' + x + '""');
    }
    else if (Condition4NotInvolvingX) {
        // do something without using x
    }
    else if (Condition5NotInvolvingX) {
        // do something without using x
    }
}
```

Comment: so what is your question ?

Comment: an only declared variable has still the value `undefined`.

Comment: In my opinion this is micro-nano-lilliputian-optimization. Actually, it`s not even *optimization*. Just assign the value of the variable once (example 1) and forget about it.

Comment: *then is it better ...?* with regard to what?

Comment: i would not use a single variable, which have a different meaning in the run, so if in the blocks are different types as assignment are used, the variable should reflect that use, and for clarification it should be more than one variable.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can assign it wherever it's convenient such that all functions/blocks that need to have access to it can do so.

That said: it's generally better to use `const` rather than `var` - `const` has block scoping (makes your code easier to understand), no hoisting (same), and disallows reassignment (same).

Though, if you wish, you can make efforts to write **pure functions** as much as they can, which means that (among other things), the only variables a function references are directly in that function's block, and not in any outer scope. Pure functions sometimes take more thinking to pull off, but they can make reasoning about larger scripts easier. Whether you want to try for that when writing code is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with fewer lines of code is better so it should be assigned once at the top not each place it's used.

Also since you wouldn't want to assign it in each block if it was used in 99 out of 100 blocks you're left with the question of exactly what ratio calls for switching from one approach (top) to the other (each block). If you just always assign it at the top, you avoid that issue.